# Multiprocessing pool extremely slow

Tags: python, neural-network, multiprocessing

I have a huge 3-dimensional list of ints (`weightedInputs`) that I am passing through a sigmoid function. For some reason, multiprocessing is slowing down my code rather than speeding it up. Can anyone tell me why my code is slower when I use multiprocessing, and how I can fix this?

This is my sigmoid activation function:

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-np.sum(x)))
```

Initial layer function:

```py
def layer(weightedInputs):
    out = list(map(sigmoid, weightedInputs))

    return np.array(out)
```

Multiprocessing:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def layer(weightedInputs):
    with Pool() as pool:
        multi = np.array(pool.map(sigmoid, weightedInputs))

    return multi
```

Comment: `numpy` is threaded (in C, so no GIL). Threading is much lower-overhead than multiprocessing. So when you add both numpy _and_ `multiprocessing` together, you get worst-of-both-worlds: You're paying all the performance costs of passing data between processes (eating `multiprocessing`-specific overhead), _and_ you're making so many threads (split between all your processes) that they're fighting for CPU time, and clearing out the CPU caches during context switches.

Comment: Is there a way to make it significantly faster?

Comment: Don't use `multiprocessing` unless you know you need multiprocessing, and you know _why_ you need multiprocessing. It's not a magic make-everything-faster switch.

Comment: ...faster than it is by default? Yes. Faster than what numpy does left to its own devices when performing a parallelization-amenable operation? No. In general, if you're using numpy to do something numpy can innately parallelize, you don't want multiprocessing. And if numpy _can't_ innately parallelize your operation, chances are good that that process is a poor candidate for multiprocessing for the same reasons it's a poor candidate for numpy to thread.

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to where this uses numpy threading: ``out = list(map(sigmoid, weightedInputs))``

Comment: I can't speak to that -- it may well _not_ be threaded, in which case you're just eating serialization/deserialization costs that exceed what you'd get by parallelizing regardless.

Comment: ...on which point: Have you tried threading explicitly? Python threads can still parallelize as long as they're spending their time with the GIL unlocked (numpy _does_ unlock the GIL when it's doing something in C), and when you use threads, data doesn't need to be copied between processes.

Comment: I have tried threading actually, but it was still slower. (with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor)

Comment: "still slower" than native just-letting-numpy-do-its-thing, or "still slower" than multiprocessing?

Comment: When I ran the whole network, it was 3x slower than the numpy version I tried, and like a billion times faster than multiprocessing.

Comment: If you monitored CPU use, was it using only one core at a time, or was the load already being distributed?

Comment: (if it's already being distributed, adding more threading means you're paying context-switch and cache-flush costs, so it just makes it worse)

Comment: (...whereas multiprocessing means you're adding context-switch and cache-flush costs, and **also** adding serialization, deserialization and transfer costs; it's more expensive than threading, so absent lock contention issues -- which are the main reason multiprocessing exists -- if adding threading made something worse, adding multiprocessing will make it even worse than that)

Comment: `sigmoid` calls `np.exp` and `np.sum`, both of which will release the GIL.

Comment: ...to be clear, transfer costs _can_ be avoided using shared memory. [Julia](https://julialang.org/benchmarks/) is a numeric-computing language that does quite well with a multi-process model, but with shared memory hosting native structures to avoid serialization/deserialization costs. But Python wasn't originally designed with high-performance computing in mind, and I'm still astonished how commonly folks try to shoehorn it into that role.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Would it make more sense to use something like numpy.vectorization since it probably also uses C? Also the reason I used python for this and not something like c or cpp is because it allowed me to do the whole thing in under 200 lines of code.

Comment: You can just pass the entire matrix to your sigmoid function...and it should be fast enough.

Comment: I just did using ``np.vectorize(sigmoid)``. Thanks for the suggestion. It's a lot faster, but still relatively slow.